# How to achieve spark-cassandra connector's "repartitionByCassandraReplica " in Kubernetes environment?

Tags: cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I saw this question ([Question Link)](https://community.datastax.com/questions/11464/repartitionbycassandrareplica-in-kubernetes.html) here. I think it might not be possible to co locate spark workers/executors on same machine in Kubernetes environment. Answer to the [question](https://community.datastax.com/questions/11464/repartitionbycassandrareplica-in-kubernetes.html) looks correct. I want to know is there any other way provided by spark-cassandra-connector to achieve similar functionality on Kubernetes environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you deploy both Cassandra and Spark in the same container then by definition the Cassandra data cannot be local to the Spark worker/executor.

As I've explained in my answer to https://community.datastax.com/questions/11464/, both the Cassandra and Spark JVMs must exist in the same container/VM/server for the data to be local. Cheers!

Comment: So only way possible is to run Cassandra and Spark  executor in same container. I am asking this because my read performance has degraded and  as of now it is not possible for me to run (Cassandra and executor) on same containers. Any other optimization technique which I can adopt to improve my read performance.

Comment: That's a completely different issue to data locality. You need to analyse your Spark job to determine where the bottleneck is and address it. Cheers!